# Should I make known strings optionals in Swift 4

Tags: ios, mobile, swift4

I was making an app when I updated to Xcode 9.3 that came with the change that `if let` statements can't have forcedly unwrapped variables `!` in the top level.

That forced me do a lot of changes because in all of my HTTP request (Don't know if helps but I use Alamofire) to a server I received variables that were Strings so I normally forcedly unwrapped them like for example in here where I recibe the price of a object.

```
if let result = response.result.value! as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

                if let Price = result["Price"] as? String!{
                    if(Price != nil){
                        self.Error = ""
                        self.price = Int(Price)!
                        completed()
                    }
                }
}
```

And now because of the update this is deprecated, what got me thinking if the right way to do this is either this way:

```
            if let Price = result["Price"] as? String?{
                if(Price != nil){
                    self.Error = ""
                    self.price = Int(Price!)!
                    completed()
                }
            }
```

Or this way:

```
            if let Price = result["Price"] as? String{
                if(Price != nil){
                    self.Error = ""
                    self.price = Int(Price)!
                    completed()
                }
            }
```

Comment: for the first line the second one is right, `if let` insurers you that the property won't be nil if program goes into if statement

Comment: You can omit the check for `Price != nil`  it the variable should be `price` - small p - and I strongly suggest you get rid of the force unwrap of the Int; you should return some sort of runtime error such as `throw`in an error if the data cannot be parsed

Comment: I try to avoid for unwrapping as much possible. Sometimes it ends up adding more code, but that is totally worth it. 2nd way with ``` as? String{ ``` looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `!` means. Even though `!` is `implicitly unwrapped`, `!` and `?` are the same thing - they both represent an `Optional` object. This means that you can still do things like this:

```
let string: String! = nil
if string == nil { return }
```

`!` should be used when you have something that could not exist, but you want the compiler to shut up because you are sure that it exists.

The reason your `result["Price"] as? String!` is deprecated is because it makes no sense. You are getting a regular optional (`String?`), casting it to a "shut up compiler, this exists" optional (`String!`), but using `if let` to make sure the code only continues if the value actually exists. So you are telling the compiler to shut up, but you are still making sure the value exists before the code continues... Doesn't make sense, right? That's why it's deprecated. `!` is doing nothing here and can be safely removed.

Your code can look like this and achieve the same result:

```
        if let Price = result["Price"] as? String {
            self.Error = ""
            self.price = Int(Price)!
            completed()
        }
```